# New as3 project framework (mvc)! Do you want to test it?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, model-view-controller, frameworks, static-libraries

I created an ActionScript3 framework by myself. Because I hate to code it out of my head. It is separated in different libs, which can be combined.
The whole code is well documented and the docs are including some examples.

The main usage is as **MVC project framework** and now I am at a point, when I can release it. But I still want to work on it to extend and improve it. And that is the point where I need a little help. I'm pretty sure you will find some issues in it. That could be in the understanding of it, the way you use it or, in worst case, a bug in the code.

So if you would like to, here is the link: http://codeboxes.com/

And by the way: I published it under the MIT Licence, so you can do what ever the fun you want with it. ;)
But it is not open source!

Comment: @null, that is not a constructive response to a new user who is unfamiliar with SO. codeboxes, This kind of question is best posted on [codereview.se]. Please read the [Help Centre](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to format your question first though.

Comment: *"I published it under the MIT Licence"* ... *"But it is not open source!"* ... uuum....?

Comment: Too many mvc framework out there and most cases they don't even bring anything useful or new to the table. If it's not open source then nobody will use it period cos it's not that useful and not that original.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for commenting and viewing my question for help. All what you said has a valid point. I will close this and think about the OpenSource thingy.